# upgrade process stuck while Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, mysql

I tried to do upgrade and its been "unpacking" for too long (20 minutes) is it normal? Not responding to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> either. What to do next?

```
shubhendu@shubhendu-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/opt$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-21 linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-21-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  boot-repair boot-sav boot-sav-extra dnsmasq-base file-roller fwupd
  gnome-shell-common google-chrome-stable initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin
  initramfs-tools-core libdfu1 libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libfwupd1 libglib2.0-0
  libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libmysqlclient20 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0
  libnma-common libnma0 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 network-manager-gnome
  python3-software-properties shared-mime-info snapd
  software-properties-common software-properties-gtk valgrind wget
37 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 87.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,378 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 google-chrome-stable amd64 51.0.2704.103-1 [49.2 MB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 boot-sav all 4ppa38 [416 kB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libexpat1-dev amd64 2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.2 [115 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libexpat1 amd64 2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.2 [71.3 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-data all 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 [132 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-bin amd64 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 [39.4 kB]
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libglib2.0-0 amd64 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 [1,118 kB]
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 boot-repair all 4ppa38 [11.5 kB]
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 boot-sav-extra all 4ppa38 [142 kB]
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 wget amd64 1.17.1-1ubuntu1.1 [298 kB]
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1 [6,120 kB]
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-common all 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1 [17.0 kB]                                    
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-client-5.7 amd64 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1 [1,695 kB]                             
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-5.7 amd64 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1 [2,587 kB]                             
Get:15 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server-core-5.7 amd64 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1 [7,503 kB]                        
Get:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools all 0.122ubuntu8.1 [8,602 B]                                    
Get:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools-core all 0.122ubuntu8.1 [42.2 kB]                               
Get:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 initramfs-tools-bin amd64 0.122ubuntu8.1 [10.8 kB]                              
Get:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 shared-mime-info amd64 1.5-2ubuntu0.1 [405 kB]                                  
Get:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 dnsmasq-base amd64 2.75-1ubuntu0.16.04.1 [294 kB]                               
Get:21 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 file-roller amd64 3.16.5-0ubuntu1.1 [303 kB]                                    
Get:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libdfu1 amd64 0.7.0-0ubuntu4.2 [42.4 kB]                                        
Get:23 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libfwupd1 amd64 0.7.0-0ubuntu4.2 [27.7 kB]                                      
Get:24 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 fwupd amd64 0.7.0-0ubuntu4.2 [86.4 kB]                                          
Get:25 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 gnome-shell-common all 3.18.5-0ubuntu0.1 [609 kB]                           
Get:26 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libmysqlclient20 amd64 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1 [811 kB]                               
Get:27 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libnm-gtk0 amd64 1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [70.0 kB]                               
Get:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libnm-gtk-common all 1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [5,344 B]                           
Get:29 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 network-manager-gnome amd64 1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [290 kB]                     
Get:30 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libnma0 amd64 1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [66.0 kB]                                  
Get:31 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libnma-common all 1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 [5,328 B]                              
Get:32 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1 [10.1 kB]                                    
Get:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 software-properties-common all 0.96.20.1 [9,428 B]                              
Get:34 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 software-properties-gtk all 0.96.20.1 [47.2 kB]                                 
Get:35 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 python3-software-properties all 0.96.20.1 [19.6 kB]                             
Get:36 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.0.9 [4,355 kB]                                                    
Get:37 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 valgrind amd64 1:3.11.0-1ubuntu4.1 [11.0 MB]                                    
Fetched 87.9 MB in 24min 24s (60.0 kB/s)                                                                                                             
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 275711 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libexpat1-dev_2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1-dev:amd64 (2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.2) over (2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libexpat1_2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.2) over (2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-data_2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-data (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (2.48.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-bin_2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-bin (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (2.48.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-0_2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) over (2.48.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../wget_1.17.1-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wget (1.17.1-1ubuntu1.1) over (1.17.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../google-chrome-stable_51.0.2704.103-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (51.0.2704.103-1) over (51.0.2704.84-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) over (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) over (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.7_5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) over (5.7.12-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
Processing 1 changed doc-base file...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1) ...
(Reading database ... 275711 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
```

Comment: Do you still facing this problem? Could you add output of `df`, it could be a free space issue

Comment: Last time I got this kind of issue, this was caused by my Exoscale hosting service, due to probably a replication issue on their server. Support changed me on a new server and then everything ran smoothly again.

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue when I upgrade packages in ubuntu 16.04 with `sudo apt upgrade`.

I solved this by manually stop mysql service.

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
```

It take a while for this, but after the service stop, the upgrade process will continue.

Comment: thanks for this idea! 
service stop took to long for me, so I found the mysql process with 
"ps aux | grep mysql" 
and kill -9'ed it  
and it continued (same idea)..

Comment: Had the same problem with ubuntu 17.10 and mysql 5.7.22, but it was enough to to run `sudo kill {id_of_the_process}` for those processes.

Comment: I just now had the same problem with Samba4, during a do-release-upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04. The `nmbd stop` process was hung; a kill -9 sorted it out and the upgrade immediately continued.

Comment: ugh. later on, I had to manually kill a Samba 4.3 process during the same upgrade - hung on "screen-cleanup" towards the end of the upgrade. FYI.